# How to apply Font Styles to PDF by using Dynamic Reports?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, vaadin

Project Description:

[image]

I have generated a report and exported to pdf by using dynamic reports and Vaadin. When i tried to apply different font Styles to report its not working.I have included ttf files, xml and .propeties file which is there in one example and I tried running the report through java application without using vaadin, it works fine. But when I include vaadin and run through Tomcat Server its not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: We need more details to see what happens (or not)

Comment: "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Roboto' is not available to the JVM." Im getting this kind of error.Here is a link 
(http://www.dynamicreports.org/documentation/fonts). according to the steps in that i followed.when i use normal java application to run the code font styles are applied. but the problem occured when i use vaadin or servlet.

Comment: So this means that it does not find the font on your servlet JVM environment. Are you sure the font file can be resolved inside your servlet?

Comment: I Have tried that one same issue was happens.

Comment: How do you reference the font file?

Comment: <fontFamily name="Roboto">
  <normal>com/WebClassExample/Roboto-Black.ttf</normal>
 
  <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
  </fontFamily>

Comment: This font.xml file place under WEB_INF/lib folder

Comment: And the font itself is under `WEB-INF/com/WebClassExample/` ?

Comment: No. I created a package named com.WebClassExample and placed the ttf file in that package.

Comment: For some reason it does not find the font (Or font declaration) http://dynamicreports.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1113&p=3917

Comment: I added my project structure above, in project description. please have a look.